# How is thermodynamic pressure a measure of total internal energy (translational, vibrational and rotational)?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I read that mechanical and thermodynamic pressures are different and the distinction is explained saying that:
"The mechanical pressure is a measure of the translational energy of the molecules. The thermodynamic pressure, on the other hand, is a measure of the total energy, which might include additionally vibrational and rotational modes."
This does not seem to make sense because thermodynamic pressure is related to temperature which is only a measure of average *translational* kinetic energy, and density (for ideal gasses). Please explain.

Comment: Is this atkin's physical chemistry :P? It's a confusing book, there are better options if you are interested in p chem still.

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: I came across it on a CFD course while studying Stokes hypothesis. I searched about it online and found a paper, "STOKES’ HYPOTHESIS FOR A NEWTONIAN, ISOTROPIC FLUID" by Mohamed Gad-el-Hak that said this.

Answer (score 0):

The source appears to be using non-standard terminology. Either they are using the term "pressure" for something other than a component of stress (force per unit area) or they are separating out contributions to pressure and giving them non-standard names.